# Defining Swift protocol-required initializer in C

Tags: ios, c, swift, objective-c, foundation

I have a C enumeration that's I've annotated for bridging into Swift, and I have a corresponding C function that's supposed to take a raw integer and convert it into a valid case of my enumeration:

```c
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RSClockPunchStatus) {
    RSClockPunchStatusUnknown = -1,
    RSClockPunchStatusIn = 0,
    RSClockPunchStatusOut = 1
} NS_SWIFT_NAME(ClockPunchStatus);

RSClockPunchStatus RSClockPunchStatusFromInteger(NSInteger integer) CF_SWIFT_NAME(ClockPunchStatus.init?(rawValue:));

RSClockPunchStatus RSClockPunchStatusFromInteger(NSInteger integer) {
    switch (integer) {
        case RSClockPunchStatusIn:
        case RSClockPunchStatusOut:
            return integer;
        default:
            return RSClockPunchStatusUnknown;
    }
}
```

I would like this function to bridge into Swift as the required implementation of `RawRepresentable`'s [`init?(rawValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable/1538354-init). However, it seems that with this setup, calling `ClockPunchStatus(rawValue: NSNotFound)` (for example) initializes a new case with a `rawValue` of `NSNotFound`, instead of clamping to `.unknown`. How can I create a C function to create an enumeration case from a raw value, and have it bridge into Swift as an initializer?

Comment: Have you checked if your C function is called at all (e.g. by setting a breakpoint)?

Comment: I have, and it doesn't seem to be

Comment: I get a "'swift_name' attribute has invalid identifier for base name" for the CF_SWIFT_NAME declaration. Actually I don't know if it is possible at all to map a C function to an optional initializer. https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md does not mention that case.

Comment: I *assume* that this is not possible, because optional integers or optional enums can not be represented in (Objective-)C. – But you can map the C function to a custom (non-failable) initializer `ClockPunchStatus.init(rv:)`.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give that a try. Ultimately, I'd like to block or override the default failable initializer generated by `RawRepresentable` internally. Ideally, I'd like to also name it `init(rawValue:)` and just have it be non-failing (as I could when I had previously defined this `enum` in Swift), but renaming it something similar but different to avoid the illegal redefinition error would probably be ok, too. Thanks for your help!